# Writing at the right side of a tikz drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do something like this:
[image]

I currently have this, but I can't manage to write next to the tikz drawing.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
    \section{Conjugado de un complejo}
        Sea $z=a+bi$ un numero complejo. Se define el conjugado de $z$ y se representa por $\overline{z}$, como el numero complejo $\overline{z}=a-bi$.\\\\
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=50pt,y=50,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
            \draw[<-] (0,0) -- (0,3);
            \draw[->] (-0.5,1.5) -- (2,1.5);
            \draw[-] (0,1.5) -- (1,2.5);
            \draw[-] (0,1.5) -- (1,0.5);
            \draw[dotted] (1,2.5) -- (1,0.5);
            \draw (1.3,0.5) node {$z$};
            \draw (1.3,2.5) node {$\overline{z}$};
            \foreach \Point in {(1,0.5),(1,2.5)}{
        \node at \Point {\textbullet};
    }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}\raggedleft
            Propiedades:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Conmutativas: $z+w=w+z$ y $zw=wz$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{minipage}
        \noindent
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Okey, already edited!

Comment: Make the second minipage wider.  `\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth} Propiedades:`